# find timeout links in a php script

Tags: php, nginx, timeout

i have a php script that looks like this:
admin.php?action=plugins&operation=config&do=92

in the php file there are multiple includes and other functions, every time i load it, there might be a bad link that causes the whole page loads after it timeouts(usually exactly 2.1 or 2.1 minutes by chrome's debugger).

my question is how do i find this bad link(s) that was sent to the server to be processed/connected, and eventually timedout?

error_reporting reported nothing useful. i've been trying to see if xdebug works, but i have 0 idea on how to use it. i need a way to find the bad link/ip/hostname without going through every piece of code.

any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Is this something that checks on the developer site whether a new version of their plugin is available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem with tcpdump under ssh.

using tcpdump i was able to see all the connections my server makes, and from there i tested each IP when loading that specific page, and ping of the ip got timed out from a ping.

and i REJECTED the ip in my iptables and fixed the problem permanently.

Answer (score 0):

What i am able to understand is once you type url then it will send request to your admin.php script this sends back the response to your browser but the response has lot of js / css/ image files which has bad links and to figure out bad links you can use fiddler. This will tell what all request your page sends and to which urls. Fiddler will show you which request  takes how much time in loading.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, what is causing delaying are includes and/or requires on the server side.

If that´s the case, you could put some lines with timestamps to see which one is causing issues, for example:

```
echo "Start:".date("H:i:s");
require_once("lib1.php");
echo "lib1 loaded at :".date("H:i:s");
include("lib2.php");
echo "lib2 loaded at :".date("H:i:s");
.....
```

Then, you can use your favorite browser network panel to see the response content, that will tell you which one causes the delay.